# C# MySQLCommand bulk update fails

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update, bulk

I'm using MySQLCommand to work with our MySQL database.

No problems doing a single update, but when I try to do a bulk update, Visual Studio crashes with "vshost32.exe has stopped working".

My bulk updates are build like "update xx where xx; update yy where yy;".

VS crashes even if there are just 2 updates in bulk update.

Any ideas for what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using this solution instead, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html